# R - add together two columns with suffixes after a merge

Tags: r, merge

I've merged together two dataframes with identical column names but different values, apart from the unique key ID1.

```
collated <- merge(data1,data2, by=c('ID1'))
```

In the merged dataset, the suffixes clearly indicate the dataset that the columns came from. i.e. `a.x`, `a.y`, `b.x`, `b.y`, `c.x`, `c.y`, etc.

However, I'm not going to know the name of the columns in advance. Is there a quick way to subtract `a.x` from `a.y`, `b.x` from `b.y`, `c.x` from `c.y` without knowing the bit before the suffix in advance? That is to create `collated$a.z <- collated$a.x - collated$a.y` but without knowing that the columns are called `a` in advance (and the same for b, c, etc)

I could probably do this by parsing through the colNames but I wasn't sure if there was an obvious alternative I might be missing. @Frank suggested using `data.frame(data1[1], data2[-1]-data1[-1])`. However, this comes up with an error `‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames` because the frames are different sizes.

Note: Example dataset can be created by:

```
set.seed(45) 
data2 <- data.frame(ID1= rep(1:200), a= rnorm(400), b= rnorm(400), c= 
rnorm(400), d= rnorm(400))
data1 <- data.frame(ID1=
rep(1:200), a= rnorm(200), b= rnorm(200), c= rnorm(200), d=
rnorm(200))
```

Comment: `data.frame(data1[1], data2[-1]-data1[-1])`

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't anticipated a linked problem when I wrote the question. If the data2 <- data.frame(ID1= rep(1:200), a= rnorm(400), b= rnorm(400), c= rnorm(400), d= rnorm(400)). I get the error "Error in Ops.data.frame(data2[-1], data1[-1]) : ‘-’ only defined for equally-sized data frames". I have updated the question to reflect this issue.

Comment: Well, there's `data.frame(data2[1], Map(\`-\`,data1[-1],data2[-1]))`. Here, because it's working with vectors, `-` will do the usual recycling.

Comment: If you've already merged, `dplyr`'s `select` has nice helper functions for picking columns. In this case, `ends_with` is useful: `select(collated, ends_with('x')) - select(collated, ends_with('y'))`. It has a lot of nice join functions, as well, especially if it starts to get more complicated than the one here.

Comment: To save the `ID1` column with the approach from the previous comment: `select(collated, ID1) %>% bind_cols(select(collated, ends_with('x')) - select(collated, ends_with('y')))`

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this succinctly with {powerjoin} :

```
library(powerjoin)
res <- power_left_join(data2, data1, by = "ID1", conflict = `-`)
head(res)
#   ID1           a          b           c          d
# 1   1  0.39817075  0.1467486  1.72932602  1.8695649
# 2   2  0.08119715 -1.9551363 -0.58216793  3.0525365
# 3   3 -0.38262213 -0.7642318  0.07737453  1.1783046
# 4   4 -1.01591432  0.3900114 -0.75116672  0.3287219
# 5   5 -0.26112151 -1.4333588 -0.51665036 -0.8413423
# 6   6 -0.92123205  0.1632439  0.81327403 -0.1760599
```